# Default SET NOCOUNT ON in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

**ISSUE**

How to set SQL Server 2012 to respond like SQL Server 2005 for a particular web application.

**BACKGROUND**

We have a legacy application in IIS 7.5 ASP 2.0 running in an application pool with "Enable 32-Bit Applications" set to true. It works fine when pointing to our SQL Server 2005 database. However, when we point it to our database upgraded to a SQL Server 2012 (not in compatibility mode) it crashes with the error message: ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'. If I add SET NOCOUNT ON to the stored procedure where the error is occurring at I can get past the error.

The application runs just fine in IIS 7.5 ASP 2.0 when using the database on our old SQL Server 2005.

Comment: We are using ASP 3.0 with SQL Server 2012 without this problem, maybe it is an incompatibility with the ADO version, what version are you using ? we use 2.8

Answer (score 2):

You can make set NOCOUNT on for a database instance by using:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure‘user options’,‘512’
```

but you should be aware of the downsides of doing this at instance level rather than in each stored procedure, SSMS will no longer report how many rows were returned.